# Converting biom to classic format?

Tags: qiime, biom

Is it still possible to convert .biom tables from QIIME to QIIME’s "classic" OTU table format to use with Explicet?
I've tried running the command from biom-format.org

> biom convert -i table.biom -o table.from_biom_w_taxonomy.txt --to-tsv --header-key taxonomy

but gives back an error:

> biom convert: error: no such option: --to-tsv

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of biom are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I honestly don't know which version is installed on our cluster. I'm assuming it's the most recent one. That being said, I've figured out the problem! I should have been using

'biom convert -i input.biom -o output.txt -b --header-key taxonomy'

Comment: try doing: `biom show-install-info` the version number should be at the bottom. The reason why you are getting this error is likely because you have an older version of biom and you need to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using QIIME too and went through the tutorial from [Wernerlab](http://wernerlab.org). Here I've successfully converted a .biom table into a text file, also with the `biom convert` command. Maybe you can find clarification in the command line [there](http://www.wernerlab.org/teaching/qiime/overview/c):

```
biom convert -i otu_table.biom -o otu_table_tabseparated.txt -b --header-key="taxonomy" --output-metadata-id="Consensus Lineage"
```

Cheers, 
Dennis